# Treeview node image change at run-time

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview

On a form there is a treeview, filled up with some hierarchical data. Treeview is linked to an imagelist. Pretty simple, isn't it?

There is a such moment - after a specific action (ex. status change) - for a specific node I need to clear it's image - only text. 
I try code this next way:

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.SelectedImageIndex = -1;
treeView1.SelectedNode.ImageIndex = -1;
```

but not work - image persists.

Is any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found solution myself.
Firstly - response to my question is no, but there is a trick - on form load I'm adding dynamically a transparent image:

```
 Bitmap mockBmp = new Bitmap(16, 16);
 using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(mockBmp))
            g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
 //add images to list
 this.imageList1.Images.Add("RootNode", mockBmp);
```

and after that when I need to "clear" the image of a node - I have only to set this image to that node.

Comment: You fired first :) Nice, because it's runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can trick it by adding a blank picture to your ImageList.